# Printing out BST nodes in order - only printing first node?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I expect to print out `[6,5,10`

instead I only get `10` :

```
class BST:
  arr = []

  def __init__(self):
    self.height = 0
    self.key = 0
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.key)

  def populate(self):
     print("populating")
     print(self.key)

     if (self.left != None):
       BST.arr = BST.arr + [self.left.populate()]

     if (self.right != None):
       BST.arr = BST.arr + [self.right.populate()]

     return self.key

m1 = BST()
m1.key = 10
m2 = BST()    
m2.key = 5
m1.left = m2

print(m1.left != None)

m3 = BST()
m3.key = 6
m2.left = m3

res = m1.populate()
print(res)
```

Comment: Why do you expect a list? `populate` returns `self.key`, which is defined as an `int` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that does in order traversal:

```
def inOrder(node, order):
    if node is not None:
        inOrder(node.left, order)
        order.append(node.key)
        inOrder(node.right, order)
```

You can write a wrapper function that does return a list and use it like this:

```
def inOrder(root):
    order = []
    inOrder(root, order)
    return order
```

Edit: Or you can do that with one function like this:

```
def inOrder(node):
    if node is None:
        return []

    return inOrder(node.left) + [node.key] + inOrder(node.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to update your `populate` method:

```
class BST:
  arr = []

  def __init__(self):
    self.height = 0
    self.key = 0
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.key)

  def populate(self):
    self.arr = []
    temp = self
    while temp.left != None or temp.right!=None:
        self.arr.append(temp.key)
        if temp.left!=None:
            temp = temp.left
        elif temp.right!=None:
            temp = temp.right
        if temp.left == None and temp.right==None:
            self.arr.append(temp.key)
    return self.arr
m1 = BST()
m1.key = 10
m2 = BST()    
m2.key = 5
m1.left = m2

print(m1.left != None)

m3 = BST()
m3.key = 6
m2.left = m3

res = m1.populate()
print(res)
```

Output:

```
True
[10, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I tried updating that populate method, leaving nothing else changed. The output is True, [] instead of  [6,5,10]

Comment: I have added the full code. The output is `[10, 5, 6]` as I traverse from the top. If you want to get `[6, 5, 10]` as output just return reversing the array as `return self.arr[::-1]`